# Authenticity of follwing Hadith e Qudsi

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I read following Hadith e Qudsi on a website. What is its authenticity? From which book it is from?

> O son of Adam! Do not be afraid of any power or sovereignty as long as
>   My Sovereignty remains, and My sovereignty never ceases! O son of
>   Adam! Don't fear restricted sustenance as long as My storehouses are
>   full, and My storehouse are never empty. O son of Adam! Don’t ask for
>   anyone but Me; if you ask for Me you will find Me, and if you miss Me
>   you will miss all the goodness! O son of Adam! I created you to
>   worship Me, so don't play. I have already set your share of substance
>   in this world, so don't make yourselves tired. I swear by My Glory and
>   Might, if you are pleased with what I have allocated for you, I will
>   bring comfort to your heart and body and you will praised by Me; on
>   the other hand, if you are not content with what I have allocated for
>   you, I swear with My Glory and Might that I will set the world loose
>   on you in which you will run just like animals run in the wild and you
>   will still not get more than what I originally allocated for you. O
>   son of Adam! Don't ask me for tomorrow's sustenance, just as I have
>   not asked you for tomorrow's deeds. O son of Adam! I love you, so by
>   My right over you, love Me!

Comment: Would you mind sharing the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the hadith on [this website](https://sufilive.com/Fajr-Sohbah-at-Somali-Mosque-Audio--6058-EN-print.html).

And found fatwas saying that this hadith doesn't exist in any hadith compilation.
It is rather mentioned as a quote of Ka'ab al-Ahbaar which he found in the Torah according to ibn 'Arabi ابن عربي in his al-Futuhaat al-Makiyyah الفتوحات المكية and in al-Mustatraf min Kulli fannin Mustadhraf المستطرف في كل فن مستظرف of al-Abshyhy الأبشيهي both didn't quote a connected chain of narrators therefore one could safely consider this is a fabrication or (and this is the best case) among the israeliyaat as neither the sources are reliable hadith sources nor do they quote any chain to the supposed source (Ka'ab al-Ahbaar).

Reference [ad-Dorar](https://dorar.net/fake-hadith/684) and fatwa islamweb #[43669](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/43669/) in Arabic.